# Count all lists of adjacent nodes stored in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, function

There are many naive approaches to this problem, but I'm looking for a good solution. Here is the problem (will be implemented in Java):

You have a function foo(int a, int b) that returns true if 'a' is "adjacent" to 'b' and false if 'a' is not adjacent to 'b'. You have an array such as this [1,4,5,9,3,2,6,15,89,11,24], but in reality has a very long length, like 120, and will be repeated over and over (its a genetic algorithm fitness function) which is why efficiency is important.

I want a function that returns the length of each possible 'list' of adjacencies in the array, but not including the 'lists' which simply subsets of a larger list.

For example, if foo(1,4) -> true, foo(4,5) -> true, foo(5,9)-> false,  foo(9,3) & foo(3,2) & foo(2,6), foo(6,15) -> true, then there are 'lists' (1,4,5) and (9,3,2,6), so length 3 and 4. I don't want it to return (3,2,6), though, because this is simply a subset of 9,3,2,6.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Sorry I just realized I didn't explain the whole problem, and the remaining portion is what is so difficult. Lets restart. Forget the first post. That will confuse us.

Lets say there is a function foo(int[] array) that returns true if the array is a "good" array and false if the array is a "bad" array. What makes it good or bad does not matter here.

Given the full array [1,6,8,9,5,11,45,16,9], lets say that subarray [1,6,8] is a "good" array and [9,5,11,45] is a "good" array. Furthermore [5,11,45,16,9] is a "good" array, and also the longest "good" subarray. Notice that while [9,5,11,45] is a "good" array, and [5,11,45,16,9] is a "good" array, [9,5,11,45,16,9] is a "bad" array.

We wants the length counts of all "good" arrays, but not subarrays of "good" arrays. Furthermore, as described above, a "good" array might begin in the middle of another "good" array, but the combination of the two might be a "bad" array.

Comment: Define `naive approach`. Do you want something better than `O(n^2)`?

Comment: If you're doing it over and over again, and speed is more important than memory, and the list is mutating (changing slightly) between runs, it is probably worth storing a pointer to the beginning of each chain. 

That way when the list changes you are limiting what you have to poke through to update your list of chains.

Answer (score 2):

I think this `O(n)` algorithm does what you want. I doubt you can do this faster since you have to analyse each element.

```
count = 1;
for each index i from 1 to N
    if ( foo(array[i-1], array[i]) == true )
        ++count;
    else
        print count;
        count = 1;
```

This works because if a certain number breaks the adjacency chain, then none of the numbers before the number that broke the chain can be part of a longer chain, so you might as well continue from that point on.

Working this on your example:

> For example, if foo(1,4) -> true, foo(4,5) -> true, foo(5,9)-> false, foo(9,3) & foo(3,2) & foo(2,6), foo(6,15) -> true, then there are 'lists' (1,4,5) and (9,3,2,6), so length 3 and 4. I don't want it to return (3,2,6), though, because this is simply a subset of 9,3,2,6

foo(1, 4) -> true -> count = 2
foo(1, 5) -> true -> count = 3
foo(5, 9) -> false -> `print 3`, count = 1
foo(9, 3) -> true -> count = 2
foo(3, 2) -> true -> count = 3
foo(2, 6) -> true -> count = 4
foo(6, 15) -> true -> count = 5

end of array, just print count, so `print 5`. I'm guessing your example is wrong, because `(9, 3, 2, 6)` is a subset of `(9, 3, 2, 6, 15)`...

Answer (score 0):

This is, I think, in the class of longest-substring style problems which can be solved in a single pass (in `O(n)`), as long as you have the property that if the subarray from A to B is "good", then any smaller subarray is also good.

The algorithm goes like this:

- Start with a subarray consisting of the first element (or pair, or whatever the shortest possible unit is).
- March the subarray forward (i.e. advance both start and end of the subarray) until you get the answer "good".
- Advance the end of the subarray until you get the answer "bad".  The subarray just before you got "bad" was the longest good subarray at that location--count it (or save it, or whatever you wish to do with it).
- Now advance the start of the subarray until you get the answer "good"; if you catch up to the end of the subarray, slide both forwards.  Then repeat the previous step.
- When the end of your subarray hits the end of your full array, you're done.